# Can receive email, can send email to local domain, can't send email to other mailservers

Tags: server, mysql, email, postfix, mail

I've recently set up a mail-server using Postfix, Dovecot and mySQL. Everything works fine except that I can't send email to other mailservers say Google. I get the following error:

```
Aug 15 11:14:27 server postfix/cleanup[19808]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_domainaliases_maps.cf lookup error for "mygmail@gmail.com"
Aug 15 11:14:27 server postfix/cleanup[19808]: warning: 82B3F22073: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for mygmail@gmail.com -- message not accepted, try again later
```

I think that postfix tries to somehow authenticate all outgoing email addresses using virtual_alias table, but I can't figure which settings I should change to fix this.
I tried Mailx command using ssh session on mailserver and also from macOSX mail client, which both were unsuccessful with the same error.

BTW I used the guide in: https://www.exratione.com/2014/05/a-mailserver-on-ubuntu-1404-postfix-dovecot-mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, it was related to /etc/postfix/mysql*.cf files, which I entered a wrong password in one of them.
Now everything works fine!